# ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "Mongo" from... (with persist) symfony2

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, persistence, doctrine-mongodb

I am having some issue integrating mongodb with Symfony (version 2.5.0-DEV) using the doctrine mongodb cookbook on http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html.

Everything is okay up to the 'Persisting Objects to MongoDB' stage. When I add the line "`$dm->persist($script);`", nothing happens to my remote database and I get the error message:

**ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "Mongo" from the global namespace in /var/www/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/mongodb/lib/Doctrine/MongoDB/Connection.php line 283. Did you forget a use statement for this class?**

But without the persist line, the script parses without errors (but nothing happens at the remote database).

Is this particular to my Symfony version (2.5.0) and is there a workaround? I have pasted my entire script below including the use statements. Any help would be appreciated :).

```
namespace Atlas\MpBundle\Controller;
use Atlas\MpBundle\Document\Scripts;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class UserjsonController extends Controller
{
    public function showuserjsonAction()
    {
        $script = new Scripts();
        $script->setName('kingstest');
        $script->setDescription('just a desc test');
        $script->setGroup('SMS');

        $dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
        $dm->persist($script);
        $dm->flush();

        return new Response('Created New Document in scripts with script id '.$script->getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the MongoDB PHP extension installed? phpinfo() output will tell you.

Comment: Show us the config where you defined "doctrine_mongodb" as a service, because i think that the problem is there

Comment: thanks for the reply.  
Derick, when I do php -m (using cli) I can see mongo as one of the modules.  
@gprusiiski, my doctrine_mongodb is below:  

#MongoDB Configuration  
doctrine_mongodb:  
    connections:  
        default:  
            server: mongodb://192.168.101.188:27017  
            options: {}  
    default_database: mp_development  
    document_managers:  
        default:  
            auto_mapping: true

Answer (score 3):

Thanks guys. Works now. 
the extension mongo.so has to be loaded in php.ini and I edited the wrong php.ini file. Added `extension=mongo.so` to php.ini located in */etc/php5/apache2/* and now it works :)
Hopefully this can help someone in the future.